# APT ERROR (since installing multiscan:i386) : subprocess installed post-installation script gave the error value 1

Tags: apt, package-management, 17.10

I have got a big problem with my package management (apt).
I tried to install the `multiscan:i386` package and since then I always get errors when I'm using commands dealing with the package management.

I don't know if it matters, but I have got an i7-4720HQ, Ubuntu 17.10.1, 64-bit architecture and I'm normally installing amd64 packages.

```
me@LINUX:~$ sudo apt remove multiscan
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  multiscan:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1647 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 98.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 459704 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing multiscan:i386 (0.8.5-1) ...
install-info: No dir file specified; try --help for more information.
dpkg: error processing package multiscan:i386 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
install-info: No dir file specified; try --help for more information.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 multiscan:i386
```

Comment: "and 1647 not upgraded." Your system has many obsolete packages, and will probably misbehave. Bring all 1647 pacgakes up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it:

```
me@LINUX:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/multiscan.postinst -f
me@LINUX:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/multiscan.md5sums -f
me@LINUX:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/multiscan.list -f
me@LINUX:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/multiscan.prerm -f
me@LINUX:~$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq multiscan
(Lese Datenbank ... 459694 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Entfernen von multiscan:i386 (0.8.5-1) ...
```